# Invincible as an adjective for faith and attitude

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, adjective-order

Invincible means too powerful to be defeated and its another usage is invincible faith or attitude which cannot be changed. I am a bit confused with the usage in the second form. I have written a few sentences and want to ensure that i am using it correctly.

> *I have invincible trust in god and miracles.*
>
> *Indian team has invincible faith on the current form of Virat Kohli and MS Dhoni which will certainly help them in the World Cup 2019.*
>
> *Invincible faith in these so called gurus can be dangerous for society.*
>
> I have tried to use it in kind a sense of unshakable trust and unshakable faith.

Comment: **Unshakeable** works much better in each of these contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is the same in both forms.

> - Invincible army
> - Invincible faith

In both cases, the army / faith cannot be defeated.

To explain the second "form" more, if faith is defeated, the person either goes into a state of confusion / depression, or he finds faith in something else. If the faith is invincible, the faith remains there unchanged - just like the invincible army.

---

Please note that "invincible" is not the most suitable word to be associated with "faith". **"Unshakeable"** or **"unlimited"** are better fits.